# Поиск в списке нужного значения

Tags: python-3.x

Не могу понять почему index не находит в списке значение?

```
text = ['Hello',',','welcome','to','the','intimacy','vocabulary','lesson',',','let`s','start','.']
len_text = len(text)
since = list (",")
id_since = text.index(since, 0, len_text)
print (id_since)
```

Вот проблема

```
id_since = text.index(since, 0, len_text)
ValueError: [','] is not in list
```

Comment: Какая стоит задача? Найти определённое значение в списке?

Comment: Нужно узнать индекс определенного значения списка.

Comment: А если несколько одинаковых значений в списке?

Comment: Нужно вывести все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `index` возвращает только первое вхождение элемента в список. К тому же в этой строке

```
since = list (",")
```

вы создаёте список, состоящий из одного элемента `[","]`, а потом пытаетесь найти этот список в списке `text`.

Задачу можно решить следующим образом. С помощью функции `enumerate` формируем список кортежей вида (индекс, значение),  проверяем совпадает ли значение с заданным и выводим его индекс

```
text = ['Hello',',','welcome','to','the','intimacy','vocabulary','lesson',',','let`s','start','.']
print(*[i for i, j in enumerate(text) if j == ","])
```

Comment: Да это хорошее решения, я хотел использовать enumerate но подумал что она не подходит. А так почему index не справилась с задачей?

Comment: Метод `index` возвращает индекс первого вхождения элемента в список

Comment: Формат метода 
index(<Значение>[, <Начало>[, <Конец>]]) 

Метод  index()  возвращает индекс элемента, имеющего указанное значение. Если значение не входит в список, то возбуждается исключение  ValueError . Если второй и третий параметры не указаны, то поиск будет производиться с начала и до конца списка. 

Пример: 
    >>> arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1] 
    >>> arr.index(1), arr.index(2) 
    (0, 1) 
    >>> arr.index(1, 1), arr.index(1, 3, 5) 
    (2, 4) 
    >>> arr.index(3) 
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>

Comment: Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) Python: `list.index(x) Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.` Т.е. возвращает индекс первого элемента значение которого равняется x. В противном случае выкинет исключение ValueError.